# r.in.xyz doesn't work in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, lidar

I have these LIDAR data *.xyz files (1st col x, 2nd col y, 3rd col z)

```
485000.16 6508997.48 1.84
485001.27 6508998.92 1.86
485001.02 6508996.68 1.85
485000.77 6508994.45 1.79
485000.52 6508992.19 1.79
485000.02 6508987.69 1.74
485000.23 6508974.93 1.89
485001.02 6508981.87 1.86
485001.54 6508986.50 1.72
485002.32 6508993.34 1.72
```

...and I want to import them to GRASS GIS. I've tried with one file but r.in.xyz doesn't seem to work. All the program says is that:

```
r.in.xyz
input=C:\Users\Siim\SkyDrive\Dokumendid\kool\magistritoo\lidarandmed\filtreeritud\508485.xyz output=508485 fs= 
Reading data ...
Writing to map ...
r.in.xyz complete. 0 points found in region.
(Mon Feb 09 20:17:26 2015) Command finished (1 sec)
```

Comment: Did you really set the field separator properly? I see empty rather than fs=" ". Or simply use fs=space to get the command working for your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks to me like you have the x and y mixed up. Your region's north is 485999 but the maximum y in the input file is 6508999. Try setting the region as:

```
g.region -p n=6509000 s=6508000 e=486000 w=485000 res=2
```

Then do your r.in.xyz command.

Answer (score 4):

As the result is a raster, you need to fix the region before importing the points. Unfortunately, [r.in.xyz](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.in.xyz.html) does not allow you to do that directly (as other commands).

Whith your 10 points in the GRASS shell (or in the Command console):

```
r.in.xyz input=test.xyz  output=testxyz  x=1 y=2 z=3 fs=' ' 
Reading data ...
100%
Writing to map ...
100%
r.in.xyz complete. 0 points found in region.
```

**The message specifies that no point has been found in the current region**.

Many solutions are proposed in [GRASS wiki: import XYZ](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Import_XYZ):

For example, a solution with the s flag:

```
 r.in.xyz -s input=test.xyz  output=test2xyz  x=1 y=2 z=3 fs=' ' 
 Range:     min         max
 x: 85000.160000 485002.320000
 y: 6508974.930000 6508998.920000
 z:    1.720000    1.890000
```

Fix a new region with these parameters

```
 g.region n=6508998.920000 s=6508974.930000 e=485002.320000 w=85000.160000  res=2
```

And import the file:

```
 r.in.xyz input=test.xyz  output=test2xyz  x=1 y=2 z=3 fs=' ' 
 Reading data ...
 100%
 Writing to map ...
 100%
 r.in.xyz complete. 9 points found in region.
```

### New

Your region is not correct, you have interchanged the x (west, east) and y (south-north) in the definition of the region.

If the result of `r.in.xyz -s` is :

```
x: 484999.980000 485999.980000  -> w and e
y: 6507999.880000 6508999.860000 -> s and n
z: 0.230000 6.160000
```

You fix the region with:

```
g.region n=6508999.860000  s=6507999.880000 e=485999.980000  w=484999.980000  res=2
```

and the result is

```
g.region -p
projection: 99 (Lambert Conformal Conic)
.... 
north:      6508999.86
south:      6507999.88
west:       484999.98
east:       485999.98
....
```

And not:

```
north: 485999.98
south: 484999.98 
west: 6507999.88 
east: 6508999.86
```

As in you case

Comment: I don't know, but in my case, no syntax error (I am not on Windows) Try with another name for output (not beginning with a number)

Comment: I got everything OK with that previous syntax error, but now I have problem with importing *.xyz file although region is set. It says: Reading data ...
Writing to map ...
r.in.xyz complete. 0 points found in region.

Comment: I run an automated GRASS script several times a day with exactly the commands that gene suggested. So it most certainly *DOES* work. Can you report the output of r.in.xyz -s, and also g.region -p ??

Comment: r.in.xyz -s input=C:\Users\Siim\SkyDrive\Dokumendid\kool\magistritoo\lidarandmed\filtreeritud\508485.xyz output=508485 fs= x: 484999.980000 485999.980000
y: 6507999.880000 6508999.860000
z:    0.230000    6.160000
Range:     min         max
(Wed Feb 11 16:14:30 2015) Command finished (1 sec)

Comment: g.region -p                                                                     
projection: 99 (Lambert Conformal Conic)
zone:       0
datum:      towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0
ellipsoid:  grs80
north:      485999.98
south:      484999.98
west:       6507999.88
east:       6508999.86
nsres:      2
ewres:      1.99996
rows:       500
cols:       500
cells:      250000
(Wed Feb 11 16:16:21 2015) Command finished (0 sec)

Comment: Look in the answer, you have interchanged the x (west, east) and y (south-north) in the definition of the region.